# Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong with this SVG/Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have put together some SVG circles, with the colour of the circles supposed to alternate on each click between blue and red.

I'm getting some inconsistent behaviour from this, as when I click on the circles in my localhost environment, it works, but the colour doesn't change to red until the second click.

When I put the code into jsFiddle, one of the circles works, one doesn't, even though the code is the same, and they both give the same error in the console

> [Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: changeColor1
>       onclick (_display:79)

```js
     var shapeClick =     document.getElementById("circle0").addEventListener("click", changeColor);
        var clicks = 0;
        var colorToggle = true;

        function changeColor() {
          var color = colorToggle ? "#ff0000" : "#1dacf9";
          circle0.setAttribute('fill', color);
          colorToggle = !colorToggle;
        }


        var shapeClick = document.getElementById("circle1").addEventListener("click", changeColor1);
        var clicks = 0;
        var colorToggle = true;

        function changeColor1() {
          var color = colorToggle ? "#ff0000" : "#1dacf9";
          circle1.setAttribute('fill', color);
          colorToggle = !colorToggle;
        }
```

```html
<svg id="table1" width="66%" height="100vh" viewBox="0 0 700 666">

    <circle id="circle0" class="circles" cx="170" cy="125" r="20"     fill="#1dacf9" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" onclick="changeColor()"/>

    
          <circle id="circle1" class="circles" cx="250" cy="45" r="20"      fill="#1dacf9" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" onclick="changeColor1()"/>
      
      </svg>
```

I'm sure there is a more streamline way to do this, especially if I scale it up and add 100 circles, I can't think of a way to do it without using a massive amount of code.

Comment: why do you add event inline and in js ?

Comment: The fact that the color doesn't change until the second click is probably to do with the fact that `colorToggle` is shared among both functions/circles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you are redefining variables that already exist, and both circles are referencing the same value for their toggle.

```
var shapeClick = ...

...

var shapeClick = ...
```

Also, you don't need to do `onclick="function()"` *and* `addEventListener`; they do the same thing.

As far as streamlining, there are a couple things you should do:

1. Create an object to hold toggle states. Keys should be IDs of the circles, and the values will be `true` or `false` to signify each circle's state.
2. Make **one** handler function, and use `event.target.getAttribute('id')` to identify which circle was clicked.

Should end up looking something like this:

```
var state = {};

var circleClickHandler = function (event) {
    var id = event.target.getAttribute('id');
    var color = state[id] ? "#ff0000" : "#1dacf9";
    event.target.setAttribute('fill', color);
    state[id] = !state[id];
};

// loop over each circle on the DOM
document.querySelectorAll('circle').forEach(function (element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', circleClickHandler);
});
```

Comment: Okay thank you very much this code makes much more sense now. So I could theoretically add as many circles as I want and they will all run through this one function?

Comment: Yep! The benefit of having a separate function for each circle is that you know which one was clicked in each. However, this approach is infeasible for a large number of circles, and impossible for a dynamic number of circles. Instead this one function is able to know which circle was clicked by using its ID attribute.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, thank you. I am having some trouble when I put the code into my page and change the name of the ID from circle to something else and then update the 'querySelectorAll('circle')' to match, it stops working.
Also wondering if its possible to use the state[id] to update a users value in a database, for example if its = red then -1 if its back to blue then +1?

Comment: `'circle'` in `document.querySelectorAll('circle')`is meant to select all `<circle/>` elements. It shouldn't refer to one specific circle's ID. In your HTML snippet, the circles have IDs of `circle0` and `circle1` but both are matched by the query because they are both `<circle/>` elements. It is possible to store more than just `true` and `false` in the `state` object, but note that you would have to change `color = state[id] ? '#FF0000' : '#1DACF9'` to something like `color = state[id] === 1 ? '#FF0000' : '#1DACF9'` and `state[id]  = !state[id]` to `state[id] = -state[id]`

Comment: Great thanks that makes sense now. Would it be necessary to store more than one state In order to have it effect the value of a users row in an mySQL database? 
My vision of how it would work is the user would have a value of say 20 stored under their USER_ID in the database, and on their profile page if they clicked one of the circles and turned the colour to red it would reduce that value to 19? 
Im too new to PHP and JS to know if this is even possible.

Comment: If all that matters is how many are red and not *which ones* are red, then yes that would be sufficient and possible. If it is important which ones are red, you'll have to store more information than just a number for each user in the database.

Comment: Good stuff, thank you for your advice it has been very helpful  in clearing this up.

Comment: Hi Matt, I have implemented the code you posted above, it works perfectly, apart from needing a double click to get the first colour change, after that its one click each. Is it possible to change this? or will I just have to account for a double click start?

Comment: `var color = state[id] ? "#ff0000" : "#1dacf9";` When you click the first time, `state[id]` is `undefined`, so it gets set to the falsey statement, which is `'#1dacf9'` (green, and I'm assuming the default is green). You could either swap the statements: `var color = state[id] ? "#1dacf9" : "#ff0000";`, or toggle the state before checking it (i.e. move `state[id] = !state[id]` above the `var color = ...` line). The latter is probably better from a mental model perspective, it's a little easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing you opening svg tag

https://jsfiddle.net/9oagrcfu/

```
<svg>
<circle id="circle0" class="circles" cx="170" cy="125" r="20"     fill="#1dacf9" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" onclick="changeColor()"/>


      <circle id="circle1" class="circles" cx="250" cy="45" r="20"      fill="#1dacf9" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" onclick="changeColor1()"/>

  </svg>
```

Comment: No he isn't, that was just an artifact of omitting a blank line so although the code was there it didn't show. I've added a blank line and the question now shows the opening tag.

Comment: Please don't deface your posts. You can delete them though, if you think they are no longer relevant.